# javafx HTML editor compiling error

Tags: javafx-8

I get no error on compiling a simple HTML editor from JavaFX 7 and 8.

The problem is the arrow keys and backspace stop working.

All is well in the "debug" and "run time" but fails in the java executable.
Windows 7, java 1.7.6 and above.

Can someone try in Intellij 12 or 13 with ether Scene builder 1.1 or 2 and let me know if they have the same problem ?

Much appreciated or a link to the bug or a link to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if HTMLEditor sample works for you, you can find sources here: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Web/H%20T%20M%20L%20Editor

If it works you need to check your app for event handling; otherwise you met an issue and you can either try newer version of JavaFX or report a bug at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, Reloaded Win 7 and Java 7u45 with Intellij 12 and recompiled OK.

Its was something to do with my desktop setup, Cause unknown.

Sorry to all for not having a long in depth solution into it. Time constraints.